# Imported SVG rendering as string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, editorjs

I'm using the editorjs npm package and have created a custom plugin.

To display an icon for the editor an SVG has to be provided as seen below
[image]

This works when inline svg is used as seen below

```
return {
            title: 'Image',
            icon: '<svg width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 336 276" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M291 150V79c0-19-15-34-34-34H79c-19 0-34 15-34 34v42l67-44 81 72 56-29 42 30zm0 52l-43-30-56 30-81-67-66 39v23c0 19 15 34 34 34h178c17 0 31-13 34-29zM79 0h178c44 0 79 35 79 79v118c0 44-35 79-79 79H79c-44 0-79-35-79-79V79C0 35 35 0 79 0z"/></svg>',
        }
```

However when I attempt to import the SVG and use the reference instead:

```
const toolBoxIcon = require('./image.svg');
return {
            title: 'Image',
            icon: toolBoxIcon,
        };
```

It renders as string:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what needs to be done to load the SVG in the second instance.

Comment: So only one SVG is faily?

Comment: The other svgs in the screenshot are using inline import.

Comment: I guess the image doesn't exist (at this location) in the bundled directory. You might need a webpack svg loader, or configure it correctly, or put the image in the correct location, or specify the correct path. For debugging maybe try to temporarily put the image.svg manually into the bundle directory (which is probably "dist") under `/static/media/` or `/media/`. (But then you still need to fix this properly, 'dist' will be overwritten)

Comment: Sure thing. I imagine it has something to do with webpack. Thanks